# how to customize build trigger in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-api

I am new in Gitlab, i would like to understand, do we have any specific place where i can define when my build should trigger?

i saw few articles and stackoverflow answers like by default if im keeping my .yml file into the project root directory, and while Push or Merge it will be trigger the build.

But here we have both different commands either this should trigger when Push get hit either merge command get hit by developers.

please share the guide to understand the gitlab trigger.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation for the GitLab only/except feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic).

You can specify conditions that must be true for a job to run (`only`) or to not run (`except`). The conditions could be that the job only runs for a particular branch, or for tags, or you can use regular expressions against just about any available environment variable.

The following config will cause the job to run only for commits on branches beginning with 'feature/':

```
only:
  - /^feature\/.*/
```